# Silverlight MVVM Add/Edit

Tags: silverlight, mvvm, addition, edit

I have to build a form(XAML) which will be used to create a record in DB and later will be edited by passing the ID. There will be combo boxes in the form which will be populated from DB and also there will be textboxes. I dont want to duplicate the XAML for ADD and EDIT and trying to resuse the code as much as possible. How can i achive this in MVVM? I want to use the best practices of MVVM. If anybody can priovide a statring point that would be great.

Comment: This is a very general question that signals a lack of effort on your part. Try to research MVVM in general and than come back with questions about specific problems.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very general scenario.

You can create a *XAML* control/page that takes an object/instance of a specific type and allows editing properties of that object.

In case of *Edit*, you passs in an object that is prepopulated from the database.

In case of *Create*, you pass in a new instance of the type.

The caller/host would know what kind of object is passed to the editing control.

So, when that object is returned back by editing control, adding/updating to the database can be taken care of by caller/host.

Comment: Do you have an example for this? Do i need 1 view and 2 viewmodels or viceversa?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the DataForm from Silverlight Toolkit, which provides different editing modes - e.g. Add, Edit.

Here's an outline of the approach. You will need two View Models. One for the data, another for the form.

```
// FormViewModel.cs
public class FormViewModel
{
   public Customer DataItem {get; set;}

   // --------- perform action ---------------
   private ICommand _PerformActionCommand = new DelegateCommand(PerformAction);
   public ICommand PerformActionCommand {
      get { return _PerformActionCommand; }
   }

   public void PerformAction()       
   {
      if (Customer.IsNew)
          InsertCustomer(Customer);
      else
          SaveCustomer(Customer);     
   }

   // ------ Button Label --------------
   public string ButtonLabel {
      get {
         return (Customer.IsNew)? "Add": "Update";
      }
   }
}
```

Here's the form:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <local:FormViewModel x:Key="formVM" />
</UserControl.Resources>
<Button 
  Content="{Binding Path=ButtonLabel
                    Source={StaticResource formVM}}"
  Command="{Binding Path=PerformActionCommand, 
                    Source={StaticResource formVM}}" />
```